# Where can I find WW2 fuel consumption data for the key participants?

Tags: world-war-two, natural-resources

Does anyone know where I can find military fuel consumption data by the key countries involved in World War II? It would be highly appreciated if you could advise on the well-organized database.

Comment: Fuel and/or oil *production* numbers may be easier to get, and might still be what you want.

Comment: Also, this question has good answers, so I'm wondering if it answers your question: [Circa 1940, what was the oil production of each nation?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33809/circa-1940-what-was-the-oil-production-of-each-nation)

Comment: Considering the wartime status, seems like one could be used as a proxy for the other in a pinch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But, I specifically need military fuel consumption data for key participants.

Comment: All major participants strictly rationed all civilian use of "strategic materials". An assumption that military use was 90 to 95% of production is unlikely to be far off, considering that everything down to bread and eggs was treated as "strategic material" in many participant countries.

Comment: This might be a small piece of the puzzle
https://www.ibiblio.org/hyperwar/USN/ref/Fuel/index.html

Comment: Also https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/60028/what-was-the-main-purpose-in-japan-trying-to-capture-the-dutch-east-indies-oil-f/60067#60067 has info as well.

Comment: Define ‘military fuel consumption’.

Comment: Oil and the Great Powers, from Anand Toprani can help you. https://www.amazon.com/Oil-Great-Powers-Britain-Germany/dp/0198834608

Comment: @JonCuster I mean war effort fuel consumption

Comment: @T.E.D. , Pieter Geerkens, R Leonard, Jon Custer, and Jos Thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Fundamentally, in WW2 for the major combatants, everything was for the war effort. Hence, total consumption is a pretty good measure.

Comment: [The Wages of Destruction: The Making and Breaking of the Nazi Economy by Tooze](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/711592) is replete with consumption/production charts **for Germany** on most major materials.  That's a huge part of the book.  If you are truly wanting to get to this info, looking through its references and annexes would be great place to start.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes, of course. Because of that, I am looking for the consumption data. But most of the data I found is for production and estimating the share of the war effort is difficult.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Thank you, that is a very useful source for Germany's war effort. If you have references for the war effort consumption of other countries, I would greatly appreciate you sharing them.

Comment: I don't but I read Tooze a short while ago and I know that's his schtick.  His sources may very well include comparisons and charts for  multiple countries, but he himself is mostly concerned with showing how Germany was always running from one resource emergency to another.

Comment: you can also look at https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/71367/where-can-i-find-japanese-oil-production-figures-through-wwii

Comment: @RLeonard Thanks a lot!